# How do I remove permission from an app that I gave Google OAuth access to?

Tags: google-account, google-api, oauth

I gave Google OAuth access to this app that wanted to read Google Analytics API info.
http://www.panguintool.com

No problem, but now I want to take away that app's permission to read my data.  Where does Google hide these authorized apps so I can remove it?

Answer (score 68):

1. Go to [myaccount.google.com/permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)
2. Select app you want & click <kbd>REMOVE</kbd> button